# openpyxl, чтение ячейки с формулой через Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Возник такой вопрос, возможно ли при использовании библиотеки openpyxl в питоне реализовать следующую вещь:
Для примера, есть таблица Excel, ячейка А1 = 5, ячейка B1 = 4, в ячейке C1 записана формула "=A1+B1".
Код изменяет значение ячейки B1 = 2 и выводит значение ячейки C1.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("example2.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active

sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value = 2 #изменяем значение ячейки А2 с 4 на 2
wb.save("example2.xlsx") #сохраняю изменения
wb.close()

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook("example2.xlsx", data_only = True) #открываю снова, чтобы использовать параметр data_only
sheet2 = wb2.active
print(sheet2.cell(row = 1, column = 3).value)
```

Код выводит значение "None", будто бы ячейка пустая. Параметр data_only использую, т.к. без него при получении значения ячейки выводится формула, а не само значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это как-то реализовать, может быть средствами других библиотек?

Comment: Получилось решить данную проблему?

Comment: Там пересчитывать значения надо. ячейка помимо формулы содержит ещё и предпосчитанное значение этой формулы. Скорее всего, ты читаешь его, а до этого его кто-то потёр (а если бы не потёр, ты бы получил неактуальное).